# Почему из-за дочернего окна закрывается основное PyQt5

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, framelesswindowhint

В общем, извиняюсь. Код большой, а комментариев мало, уже сам немного путаюсь, но основное, что скорее всего является проблемой я пометил.

Суть проблемы: при нажатии на кнопку `"Settings"` открывается дочернее окно с настройками (будет в будущем), а при его закрывании, закрывается и основное. 
Такого не было до того, как я не убрал рамку и не установил свою кнопку выхода.

**main.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from settings import Ui_Settings


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(330, 170)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"    border: 2px solid gray;\n"
"}")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 201, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(8)
        self.lineEdit.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 50, 201, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(16)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 50, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: gray;\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 130, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: gray;\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 130, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: gray;\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 0, 31, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 0, 31, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.min)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 271, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"    font-size: 14px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;    \n"
"    font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Password"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Form", "Login"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Settings"))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "New user registration"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Register"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Login"))
        self.pushButton_4.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "Close the program"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "  Login"))

    def min(self):
        self.showMinimized()

    def onClicked(self):
        self.sett = MySettings()
        self.sett.show()

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)# Убрать рамку
        self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

class MySettings(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Settings):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MySettings, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)  # Убрать рамку
        self.old_pos = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = Widget()
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**settings.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(220, 120)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"    border: 2px solid gray;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 31, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit) # ВОТ ЭТА ВОТ ПАДЛА УБИВАЕТ ОСНОВУ

        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 0, 31, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.min)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 161, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"    font-size: 14px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;    \n"
"    font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 101, 17))
        self.checkBox.setToolTip("")
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: gray;\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: red;\n"
"    background-color: red;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 91, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.checkBox_2.setChecked(True)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_4.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "Close the program"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "  Settings"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "Show password"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Delete all accounts"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Show login"))

    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

    def min(self):
        self.showMinimized()
```

---

Собственно, как сделать, чтобы закрывалось только окно с настройками?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените строку

```
self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
```

на

```
self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.hide)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Settings(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(220, 120)
        Form.setStyleSheet("QWidget {\n"
"    background-color: white;\n"
"    border: 2px solid gray;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 31, 31))
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

#        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit) # ВОТ ЭТА ВОТ ПАДЛА УБИВАЕТ ОСНОВУ
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.hide)

        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 0, 31, 31))
        self.pushButton_5.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")

        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.min)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 161, 31))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    border:none;\n"
"    color:white;\n"
"    font-size: 14px;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;    \n"
"    font-family: Lucida Console;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 101, 17))
        self.checkBox.setToolTip("")
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 60, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: gray;\n"
"    background-color: silver;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip("")
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"    background-color: gray;\n"
"    font-weight: bold;\n"
"    border-bottom: 2px solid black;\n"
"    border-right: 2px solid black;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    border-color: red;\n"
"    background-color: red;\n"
"}")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(Form)
        self.checkBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 40, 91, 17))
        self.checkBox_2.setStyleSheet("QCheckBox {\n"
"    border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.checkBox_2.setChecked(True)
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton_4.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "Close the program"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Form", "X"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Form", "-"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "  Settings"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("Form", "Show password"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Form", "Delete all accounts"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Show login"))

    # вызывается при нажатии кнопки мыши
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = event.pos()

    # вызывается при отпускании кнопки мыши
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.old_pos = None

    # вызывается всякий раз, когда мышь перемещается
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self.old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self.old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

    def min(self):
        self.showMinimized()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]